# Kafka Generates Events Based on Schema

Tags: apache-kafka, stress-testing

Are there any tools service which will allow users to generate Kafka events based on specific schema ? Wanted to do stress testing on my Kafka Topic.

There is one tool i found : [kafka-connect-datagen](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen), what here we can't configure the bootstrap server as my topic are spread across multiple cluster ? Looking for some recommendations

Answer (score 0):

> my topic are spread across multiple cluster

Kafka topics cannot be spread across more than one cluster. Their *partitions* can be spread in *one cluster*, which only needs one bootstrap address.

---

The DataGen connectors will work fine for single clusters. Run it with different config files for unique clusters.